# Sequence notation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, notation, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

[image]

**Cor.** **Mobius Inversion Formula** for multiplicative functions.

Let $f,F$ be multiplicative functions such that $F(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}f(d)$. Then $f(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\mu(\frac nd)F(d)$.

*Proof.*

Set:

- $\vec x = (f(e))_{e\mid n}$,
- $\vec a=(F(d))_{d\mid n}$

in the Mobius Inversion Theorem to get the result. $\quad\quad\square$

---

What is this notation supposed to represent? A matrix or a sequence? How would it look explicitly?:
$\vec x = (f(e))_{e\mid n}$,
$\vec a=(F(d))_{d\mid n}$

Comment: I think it's the same as $x_e=f(e)$ and $a_d=F(d)$.